# Use findIndex() starting from element other than zero

Tags: javascript

I want to use findIndex() on an array starting from an element other than zero. I have written the below code which is working for me but is there a cleaner solution?

```
let desiredLastElementIndex = refundRequests.map((e,i) =>{
    if(i<numberOfTickets){
        return 0
    }else{
        return Math.round(e.purchasersMinimumPrice - refundRequests[i-1].purchasersMinimumPrice)
        }
        }).findIndex((e, i) => findIndex((e, i) => e !== 0)
```

For example when using indexOf I can pass the index I want to start from as the second parameter.

Ideally I'd like to do something like...

```
    let desiredLastElementIndex = refundRequests.findIndex((e, i) => {
     e.purchasersMinimumPrice !== refundRequests[i+1].purchasersMinimumPrice
}, INDEXTOSTARTFROM) + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do

```
  let desiredLastElementIndex = refundRequests.findIndex((e, i) => i >= numberOfTickets && e.purchasersMinimumPrice !== refundRequests[i+1].purchasersMinimumPrice);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a helper method called `fromIndex()` to wrap a callback function before passing it to [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). Other functions it can wrap callbacks for are [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
function fromIndex(cb, index) {
  return function (e, i, a) {
    return i >= index && cb.call(this, e, i, a);
  };
}

const array = [3, 7, 5, 1, 9];
const f = element => element > 4;

console.log(`value ${array.find(f)} index ${array.findIndex(f)}`);
console.log(`value ${array.find(fromIndex(f, 3))} index ${array.findIndex(fromIndex(f, 3))}`);
```

In your example case, the usage would look like this:

```
let desiredLastElementIndex = refundRequests.findIndex(fromIndex((e, i) => {
  e.purchasersMinimumPrice !== refundRequests[i + 1].purchasersMinimumPrice
}, INDEXTOSTARTFROM)) + 1
```

---

For some extra fun, you could define some iteratee-last curried functions specifically for `find()` and `findIndex()`:

```js
const fromIndex = (cb, index = 0) => (e, i, a) => (
  i >= index && cb(e, i, a)
);
const wrap = (impl, apply) => (...args) => (
  f => iteratee => impl(iteratee, f)
)(
  apply(...args)
);

const find = wrap((array, fn) => array.find(fn), fromIndex);
const findIndex = wrap((array, fn) => array.findIndex(fn), fromIndex);

const array = [3, 7, 5, 1, 9];
const f = element => element > 4;

console.log(`value ${find(f)(array)} index ${findIndex(f)(array)}`);
console.log(`value ${find(f, 3)(array)} index ${findIndex(f, 3)(array)}`);
```

If / when the [F# style pipeline operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator/wiki#proposal-1-f-sharp-style-only-with-await) ever makes it to the specification, that's what will make these partial functions look really appealing:

```
// find() and findIndex() defined as above
const array = [3, 7, 5, 1, 9];
const f = element => element > 4;

// value 7 index 1
console.log(`value ${array |> find(f)} index ${array |> findIndex(f)}`);
// value 9 index 4
console.log(`value ${array |> find(f, 3)} index ${array |> findIndex(f, 3)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use slice and add the index from where you want to start your iteration:

```js
function desiredLastElementIndex(arr, index) {
  const found = arr.slice(index).findIndex(el => el === 1);
  if (found < 0) { return found; }
  return found + index;
}
const arr = [1, 2, 4, 8, 5];
console.log(desiredLastElementIndex(arr, 1));
```

Comment: This is what I would do; though perhaps your example should use a variable for the slice parameter so you can also add it back into the result, for clarity? (If you do, make sure you handle the case of `res === -1` since adding to that will give the wrong result.)

Comment: tbh i didn't get what are you talking about you can edit my answer :) i f you think that you can improve it

Comment: No problem; just edited in the edge case and the addition of the offset index so the resulting index is correct for the original array :)